# Is this a legal C strdup function?

Tags: c, c-strings, strdup

I tried to make my own strdup function to practice my C skills, but I'm not sure if it's legal or not.

the function is down below:

```
char*
strdup(char* str) {
    char* dup_str;
    int len;
    for (len = 0; *str != '\0'; ++len) {
        dup_str = str;
        dup_str++;
        str++;
    }
    
    dup_str -= len;
    return dup_str;
}
```

I have tested it a bit, but I'm still not sure if it is legal. It may be completely incorrect, so I'm surprised that it works the way it does at the moment.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the new pointer by using `malloc()`.

Comment: It's invalid in multiple ways. You never actually duplicate the contents of the string `str` only the pointer.

Comment: Essentially, a `strdup` function gets the length of the input string. Allocates memory for the duplicate (including the null-terminator). And then copy the contents of the input string (preferably using `memcpy`).

Comment: To see in your testing why this is not legal: modify the result of your `strdup` function. What happens with your original string?

Comment: okay so I am completely wrong, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Parker Mason In fact your function is equivalent to char*
strdup(char* str) {
    char* dup_str = str;
    return dup_str;
} provided that the length of the source string is not gretaer than INT_MAX.

Comment: So I was on the right track (to an extent), but differed from a "normal" approach?

Comment: @ParkerMason Your function does not create a copy of a string. It just returns the same address of the first character of a string. Without using the function you can write in the caller char* dup_str = str; If you need a copy of a string you need to reserve a memory for the created copy.

Comment: "legal" is a very narrow term.  If it compiles, it is "legal".  Whether it is semantically correct is a different question.  Looks like _legal nonsense_ to me.

Comment: @ParkerMason I would not say that you was on the right track, because your function does not create a duplicate string but returns a pointer on the original string. Furthermore, your code is a hint that you still have confusions between the pointer and the pointed value. The only good track if that you cautiously asked whether you were right ;-)

Comment: @ParkerMason well, no you were totally off the right track. Your solution is plain wrong.

Comment: Okay, so I wasn't on the right track at all, and I should study the differences between pointers and pointed values. thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the undefined behaviour that occurs for strings larger than `INT_MAX` chars long, your code is equivalent to the following:

```c
char *my_strdup( char *old ) {  // XXX Shouldn't require a modifiable string.
   if ( *old ) {
      return old;               // XXX Not a pointer to a new string.
   } else {
      char* indeterminate;
      return indeterminate;     // XXX Indeterminate value.
   }
}
```

This is completely wrong. For starters, `strdup`'s main purpose is to allocate a new string, yet your function allocates no memory.

`strdup` can be summarized into four steps:

1. Determine the amount of memory to allocate.
2. Allocate memory for the new string.
3. Copy the old string into the newly-allocated buffer.
4. Return the pointer to the newly-allocated buffer.

Fixed: (Added after OP made attempt to fix in the comments.)

```c
char *my_strdup( const char* old ) {
   size_t n = strlen( old ) + 1;
   char *new = malloc( n );
   if ( !new ) {
      errno = ENOMEM;
      return NULL;
   }

   return memcpy( new, old, n );
}
```

We can also replace the other string functions.

```c
size_t my_strlen( const char *str ) {
   size_t len = 0;
   while ( *( str++ ) )
      ++len;

   return len;
}
```

```c
void *my_memcpy( void *restrict dst, const void *restrict src, size_t count ) {
   void *rv = dst;

   while ( count-- )
      *( dst++ ) = *( src++ );

   return rv;
}
```

Comment: okay I've played around with the function based on the advice I was given, and came up with: char*
strdup(char* str) {
 char* dup_str = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    int len = strlen(str);
 while (len--) {
     *dup_str = *str;
        dup_str++;
        str++;
    }
 dup_str -= strlen(str + 1);
    return dup_str;
}  does this work?

Comment: 1. `strlen` doesn't return an `int`, so you still mishandle long strings. /// 2. Don't call `strlen` more than once. /// 3. You need to handle an error from `malloc`. /// 4. You don't copy the trailing NUL.

Comment: should I use size_t instead?

Comment: That is the fix for point 1, yes.

Comment: I enjoyed working through this problem with you, thank you so much for your help :) ( I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure I've seen your helpful answers elsewhere because of the space in-between each parentheses, which I haven't seen be done very often) :D

Comment: (Spaces in parens allow vertical alignment of repeated patterns.)

Comment: @ParkerMason Spaces within parentheses are also very useful if you're working with some benighted IDE that expands double clicks out to bounding whitespace...

Comment: `memcpy( new, old, n );
   return new;` can be simply replaced by `return memcpy( new, old, n );`. The function returns always the first parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but the parenthesis are annoying for experienced C coders. ` *dst++ = *src++;`  is an idiomatic expression of the language.

Comment: The official `strdup()` also sets `errno` to `ENOMEM` when the allocation fails. Just discovered it myself when proposing my answer.

Comment: @Patrick Schlüter, Re "*the parenthesis are annoying for experienced C coders*", You don't speak for all of them, and the OP is far from an experienced C coder.

Comment: @Patrick Schlüter, Re "*The official `strdup()` also sets `errno` to `ENOMEM`*", I was relying on `malloc` setting it, but that does not appear to be portable.

Comment: @ikegami "you don't speak for all of them" I only speak for the experienced C coders that find them annoying. We're allowed to have our preferences stated too.

Comment: @ikegami as for `errno` setting it's a preference thhing also. The C standard does not ask for it, only Posix so one can choose as one wants.

Comment: @Patrick Schlüter. Yes, but you said it was true of experienced C coders. *That* is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

Before writing such a function yourself you should read the description of the POSIX function `strdup` that is also included in the C23 Standard.

The function is declared like

```
char *strdup(const char *s);
```

As you can see its single parameter is declared with the qualifier `const` because the passed source string is not changed within the function. So your function is already wrong because its declaration (its interface) only confuses users.

After this for loop

```
for (len = 0; *str != '\0'; ++len) {
    dup_str = str;
    dup_str++;
    str++;
}
```

the pointer `dup_ptr` points to the last character of the source string that is to the terminating zero character `'\0'` provided that the length of the source string is not greater than the value of the macro `INT_MAX`. Otherwise the function invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover if the passed string is an empty string then the pointer `dup_str` will stay uninitialized and the uninitialized pointer with an indeterminate value will be returned from the function.

After this statement

```
dup_str -= len;
```

the pointer `dup_str` is set to the address of the first character of the source string and this address is returned from the function.

In fact your function looks like

```
char* strdup(char* str) {
    char* dup_str = str;
    
    return dup_str;
}
```

privided that theh source string is not empty.

As you can see neither duplicate string is created. There is no great sense to write a whole function to assign one variable to another variable.

You need to reserve a memory for the duplicate string.

Let's read what is written in the **C23 Standard** (7.26.2.6 The strdup function):

> 2 The strdup function creates a copy of the string pointed to by s in
> a space allocated as if by a call to **malloc**.
>
> 3 The strdup function returns a pointer to the first character of the
> duplicate string. The returned pointer can be passed to free. **If no
> space can be allocated the strdup function returns a null pointer.**

Following this description the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * strdup( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    char *dup_str = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( dup_str != NULL ) strcpy( dup_str, s );

    return dup_str;
}
```

Instead of the call of `strcpy` you may use a call of `memcpy` like

```
memcpy( dup_str, s, n + 1 );
```

Without using the standard C string functions `strlen` and `strcpy` the function can be defined the following way

```
char * strdup( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    char *dup_str = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( dup_str != NULL )
    {
        for ( char *tmp = dup_str; ( *tmp++ = *s++ ) != '\0'; );
    }

    return dup_str;
}
```

Pay attention to that the function follows the C Standard convention for string functions and does not check whether a passed pointer is a null pointer. It is the user responsibility to pass a valid pointer.

Also you need to remember that when the created duplicate string is not needed any more you need to free the allocated memory for it using function `free()`. For example

```
int main( void )
{
    const char *source = "Hello World!";

    char *copy = strdup( source );

    if ( copy != NULL ) puts( copy );


    free( copy );
}
```

Comment: wow, that is a lot of helpful information. Thanks for clearing everything up along with the help from others :D

Answer (score 1):

You do not allocate a new string and have some other minor errors (non const parameter, uninitialized pointer on empty string).

Here an implementation following the behaviour described by `man` on Linux.
Note the setting of `errno` on allocation error.

```
 char *strdup(const char *str)
 {
     size_t len = strlen(str)+1;
     char *r = malloc(len); 
     if(r)
       return memcpy(r, str, len);
     else 
       errno = ENOMEM;
     return NULL;
 }
```

variation

```
 char *strdup(const char *str)
 {
     size_t len = strlen(str)+1;
     char *r = malloc(len); 
     return r ? memcpy(r, str, len) : (errno=ENOMEM, NULL);
 }
```